# Necesito extraer los últimos 4 caracteres en una cadena (MATLAB)

Tags: string, matlab

Buen día, ¿alguien sabe extraer los últimos 4 caracteres de una cadena en matlab 2017?

Answer (score 1):

Usa `length` para obtener la longitud de una cadena y la sintaxis `M(n:m)`, como si la cadena fuera un vector, para obtener un rango de caracteres de la misma, por ejemplo:

```
>> a='stackoverflow'
>> len=length(a);%obteniendo la longitud 
>> a(len-3:len)%con el rango len-3:len obtenemos los cuatro últimos caracteres.

ans =

flow
```